# href="#" shows full URL in status bar

Tags: javascript, html, browser

[image]

Please check attached screenshot. I am trying add a few links in my project that basically do nothing until a valid value is added. But when I look at the status bar it shows full url with # at the end of it. I would like to avoid this if possible. Is there a way I can do this? Thanks!

Here's a link to the codepen - https://codepen.io/retrn0/pen/qpjrLB

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://matthewpalmer.net/rocket/icon.png"></img>
</a>
```

Comment: That is how it works, if you do not want a link, than do not use a link.

Comment: That's because `#` is an anchor link on the current page. You can remove the `href` attribute entirely, however.

Comment: Pretty sure there is a way to change a <span> tag into an <a tag on hover. That way they won't be links until the value has been added. So in your function that adds the href= value I would also add in an onhover that changes your <nolink href="#"> into an <a href="value">. I'd look into something similar to document.getelementbyid     - I don't think there's any way to prevent a <a href="#"> URL to be displayed in the status bar as the browser wants to protect the user by letting them know where they are being linked to.

Comment: @epascarello ok, but then should't the url be https://codepen.io/retrn0/pen/qpjrLB with # at the end? the status bar url is different

Comment: because the iframe in the bottom is in a different domain https://s.codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-92431e87-0129-fa9e-27ae-a80c0ec31b5f/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can remove `href` entirely.

Alternatively, you can use `href="javascript:void(0)"` which basically does nothing when clicked on.

if you want to read more about `void` operator, you can do so [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)